# Javascript, DefaultEvent

Tags: javascript

Code below is the code with my question.

```
var links=content.getElementsByTagName("a");

for(var i=0;i<links.length;++i)
{
    links[i].onclick=function()
    {
        document.getElementById("placeholder").setAttribute("src",this.href);
        return false;
    };
}
```

Here I try to add onclick functions to the links and I succeed in making this by using the code above. However, if I **replace** the **this.href** with **links[i].href**, the default event of switching page appears. I want to know the reason.

Comment: No no no. I'm wondering why by replacing that, it didn't cancel the default event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'll happen because by the time you reach the onclick, `links[i]` will already have a different (possibly undefined) value. JS doesn't have block scope.

If you want, you could use `Array.prototype.forEach`, which takes a function, and therefore will keep scope.

Comment: Correct answer! I've found that now. Thx. Would you give me some material to learn about scope?

Comment: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/01/what-you-need-to-know-about-javascript-scope/

Comment: It's helpful. Thank you again!~